ClamAV scanning remote hosts from windows server
I am trying to find a way for ClamAV to scan remote hosts on my LAN and possibly automate this so it runs every night, I have around 10 - 15 VMs I'd like to scan and get reports for. I have installed Clamav onto a windows server on my LAN and was hoping to run scans from it. Does anyone know if this is possible?
Have looked but can't seem to find an answer for if this can be done.
My goal is to find a something that can scan my LAN for viruses and malware I know there are paid options but if anyone know if any free software that can do this that would be great.
Thanks
Nathan

What is the OS of VMs?

Windows 10 Pro.

Windows 10 Pro is the OS of the machine I am running ClamAV on. All my other VMs are a mixture of windows server 2012R2, windows server 2016 & windows server 2019.

That's a bad idea, as it will use massive network traffic. Run ClamAV local.

Ok but If I run clamAV local can it do what I asked?

How would I go about setting up clamd on multiple machines so that I can run a scan on one of my vms from my server running clamav? is that possible?

You install ClamAV on each machine and use a central monitoring tool to monitor each local ClamAV instance. Please stop asking further questions, as these are offtopic.

Flagged for Planty Off-Topic, do the same paladin ;)
